# Symfony. Count rows for entity property by entity id

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, dql

I have an article entity. Article has property views. Views table looks like

id | article_id | ip

unique(article_id, ip)

Now I do the following, i modify findAll method in ArticleRepository. Is it a right way or i can do it in article entity?

Thx for any help.

```
/**
 * Class ArticleRepository
 *
 * @package FrontendBundle\Entity
 */
class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function findAll()
    {
        if ($all = parent::findAll()) {
            foreach ($all as $article) {
                $article->setViews($this->getViews($article->getId()));
            }
        }

        return $all;
    }
    /**
     * Add view to article.
     *
     * @param int    $id Article id.
     * @param string $ip User clients ip
     */
    public function addView($id, $ip)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_em->getConnection()->insert('articles_views', [
                'article_id' => $id,
                'ip'         => $ip
            ]);
        }
        catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException  $e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return views for article.
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException If the query result is not unique.
     * @throws NoResultException        If the query returned no result.
     */
    public function getViews($id)
    {
        // here is custom sql query to get count rows from articles_views
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
return $qb
    ->select('count(t.views)')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: You dont understand me. articles_views has no entity so querybuilder will not work.

Comment: How to make query i know. I want to know is this a right way/symfony way? Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 5.1 I'm using embedded Repository method `public function count(array $criteria)`.

This method even allows you to specify parameters it will count with. Accordingly, if you want to count the number of records without applying parameters, you can simply pass an empty array to this method.